# Manually enter auth credentials in dialog

Tags: cypress

I need Cypress authenticate a XHR request done in my app. The authentication **is not** *Basic*, but *Digest*, which has made finding help harder.

There also seems to be a bug for authenticating requests, such like:

```
cy.request({
  url: 'http://postman-echo.com/digest-auth',
  auth: { user: 'postman', pass: 'password', sendImmediately: false },
})
```

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2128

I'm wondering if there is a temporary workaround involving making Cypress manually entering the credentials in the dialog?

[image]

I've looked into listening to events such as [`window:alert`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Cypress-Events) and [`window:confirm`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Cypress-Events), but these don't seem to catch the auth dialog.

**TL:DR:** How can I make Cypress enter the credentials manually in the dialog?

Answer (score 2):

`cy.visit` currently only supports sending `Basic` HTTP auth, but I've opened a feature request for digest auth: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4669

In the meantime, the workaround would be to disable HTTP authentication in your local testing environment.

Comment: There is actually support for digest, but there is a confirmed bug since last year which has yet to be addressed (see link in op). Yes, meanwhile I've solved my problem by setting a special environment where basic auth is setup, just like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

1. Try and send the username and password in the url
2. Send Auth Headers with your request

Worked fine in the below example

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HAn6B4E-Kc

Answer (score -3):

You would probably need something like this

```
    cy.visit('http://yoururl/')
    cy.get('input#username').type('username')
    cy.get('input#password').type('password')
    cy.get('button#signin').click()
```

Comment: You cannot interact with a digest authentication pop-up like that